# how to change &gt; and &lt; using xsl transforms?

Tags: xml, xslt

```
 Input    
      <p>
        &lt;mml:mrow&gt;
        &lt;mml:mi&gt;a&lt;/mml:mi&gt;
        &lt;mmml:mo&gt; &lt;  &lt;/mmml:mo&gt;
        &lt;mmml:mo&gt; &gt;  &lt;/mmml:mo&gt;
        &lt;/mml:mrow&gt;
     </p>
 Output
      <p>
       <mml:mrow>
        <mml:mi>a</mml:mi>
        <mmml:mo> &lt;  </mmml:mo>
        <mmml:mo> &gt;  </mmml:mo>
       </mml:mrow>
     </p>
```

I hope you are able to understand the scenario. I need an xslt code to perform above transformation.

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: That is an odd input and an odd output, if you use `<xsl:template match="p"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` you will get a result close to the one you described but there is no way to distinguish the `&lt;` for tags from the data so you will get e.g. `<mmml:mo> <  </mmml:mo>` and not `<mmml:mo> &lt;  </mmml:mo>`.

Comment: I have tried <xsl:template match="p"><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template> and got the similar results as you have stated but the requirement is to preserve the &lt; and &gt; in those case where they lie between some tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to parse that content with a HTML parser:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"  xmlns:d="data:,dpc" exclude-result-prefixes="d">

    <xsl:import href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="d:htmlparse(., '', false())"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDA/1 does that and the result is

```
<p>
        <mrow>
        <mi>a</mi>
        <mo> &lt;  </mo>
        <mo> &gt;  </mo>
        </mrow>
     </p>
```

Requires an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor as that HTML parser implemented in XSLT uses XSLT 2.0.

Comment: The stylesheet imports the stylesheet https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/blob/master/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl which is an error correcting XML/HTML parser implementation in XSLT 2.0 and then uses that parser to parse the contents of your `p` element into a tree of nodes which are output. As your input inside the `p` seems to be a malformed mixture of XML syntax I don't think there is any way to parse it as XML with e.g. `parse-xml` and therefore I tried whether that imported parser can handle your input and in some way it can.

Comment: The output is not the same that I wanted. Kindly refer to my output requirement.

Comment: I know but frankly XSLT is not the right tool to create such output with prefixed names like `mml:mrow` without declaring any namespace for that prefix `mml` and there is no other easy way to parse such a malformed input either as far as I know so the above is all I can suggest, you could try to postprocess the result of `d:htmlparse` on your own.

Comment: @abp10896 Note that your specification of requirements consists of one example input and output. That's not really enough to work from. There are all sorts of heuristics one could apply here to distinguish which angle brackets represent markup and which represent text content, and the right design approach can only be decided from a much more comprehensive specification. You've done well to get anyone to tackle this at all.

Comment: @MichaelKay I believe that the input/output required is explaining the problem scenario very clearly

Comment: @MartinHonnen why did the tag name got altered from mml:mi to mi ??????

Comment: Because the prefix `mml` is not declared.

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDA/2 for instance where I added the declaration on the `mrow` element and that way it is also in the output.

Comment: @abp10896 no you haven't specified the problem clearly at all. What is the rule that decides whether a `<` is the start of a tag or a less-than sign? For example, what should happen to `<a>x<y>z</a>`?

Comment: @MichaelKay there is no such case the only case that we have is of type <a>  <   </a> or <a>  >  </a>. So in such cases we need to retain the &lt; and &gt; which are enclosed between a XML tag

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "is of type". Please describe the "type". For example, will there always be exactly one angle bracket, will it always be surrounded by spaces? One instance does not define a type.

Comment: @MichaelKay The input is always of the type &lt;mml:mi&gt; (&lt;) &lt; /mml:mi&gt; . For your clarity i have plced the lt tag that is to be retained after the transformation in round brackets.

Comment: You're now closer to writing a specification, in that you've given us something resembling a regular expression describing the input you want to match and the output you want to produce from it. It's a fairly small step from there to writing a script in some text processing language like Perl or Sed to turn this non-XML into XML. Your mistake is to use the "xml" tag when it's actually a question about processing non-XML.